# Getters vs functions for internal properties

Tags: javascript

Consider this code snippet

```js
class A {
  constructor() {
   this._val = 5;
  }
  
  get val() {
    return this._val;
  }
  
  getVal() {
    return this._val;
  }
}

const a = new A();
console.log(`A.val: ${a.val}, A.getVal: ${a.getVal()}`);
```

Obtaining `_val` of object `a` works via both the accessor `get val()` as well as the regular method `getVal()`. Are there any differences between the two other than that the former exposes a property `val` on `a` whereas `getVal()` is function that is exposed as a property on `a`? Would there be any *performance*/ *coding guideline* considerations on when to adopt one over the other?

Comment: Internally those create different kindd of properties (accessor vs data property), but the only difference regarding *using* those properties is that one needs to be called as a function, as you already mentioned.

Comment: "Would there be any performance/ coding guideline considerations on when to adopt one over the other?" **YES**. When I call a method I do it with the tacit understanding that the call may have side effects, which I would be pretty surprised to see from just reading a property value. Getters should be side-effect free (including but not limited to throwing errors).

Comment: Both patterns are unnecessary ceremony in your example. Are you planning to perform side-effects?

Comment: @jsejcksn No, I don't intend to perform any side effects. In that case, are both essentially the same?

Comment: @Zoso In that case: yes, they’re the same. (Of course, with the exception that the method requires the user to invoke it using `()`.) It’s simply a decision regarding ergonomics. I’m sure you’ll get plenty of opinionated replies, but it’s just a matter of preference.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the difference:

```js
class A {
  constructor() {
   this._val = 5;
  }
  
  get val() {
    return this._val;
  }
  
  getVal() {
    return this._val;
  }
}

const a = new A();
console.log(a);
console.log(`A.val: ${a.val}, A.getVal: ${a.getVal()}`);

class B {
  constructor() {
   this._val = 6;
  }
  
  getVal() {
    return this._val;
  }
}

const b = new B();
console.log(b);
console.log(`B.val: ${b.val}, B.getVal: ${b.getVal()}`);
```

You'll notice that `get` exposes `_val` directly as a property. The function is a function that accesses `_val`. That's really the only difference. Use `get` if you just want the property to be accessible. Use the function is you want to do stuff the variable before making it accessible, like, formatting a date, for example.

Comment: I'm sorry but what's the purpose of `B`/`b` in the snippet? I get your answer's point that use functions if one needs to execute side-effect prone code but what's the difference between `A` and `B` other than that the latter doesn't have the accessor property?